# Correcting tag misspellings

Tags: support, tags

How does one merge tags?  Does it take a moderator?  (The "multicolinearity" tag is a misspelling of "multicollinearity", for example, and should be removed permanently.  Or should we allow misspelled synonyms?)

Comment: Thanks for spotting this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer you general question, you can create a synonym when you have 10K rep or are a mod (see the [privileges](https://stats.stackexchange.com/privileges) page).

Regarding your particular question about multicollinearity, I agree with Srikant's suggestion:

- Misspellings should be fixed (as in this case).
- Context differences should be handled with a synonym, e.g. modelling and modeling.

Comment: My privileges page says I can already create synonyms (which I have done as a workaround in this case).  It doesn't say anything about merging or deleting tags.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Merging and deleting tags are available to mods only (see this [meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/allow-10ks-to-merge-tags)).

Comment: Thank you for the reference to that discussion: it illuminates the issue.  I did not appreciate the irreversibility of the merging process.  The answer, it seems, is that requests for substantive changes to tags should be directed to moderators and I take it that this meta forum is the proper (and only?) mechanism to do so.

Comment: For any substantive changes to tags, just post it on meta.

Answer (score 4):

I think the we should follow the following general recipe:

- Misspellings like the one pointed out in the question should be fixed.
- Misspellings because of a difference in usage across contexts (e.g., color vs colour) should not be fixed. Instead, we should use the synonym feature for these types of misspellings.

Comment: +1 Agreed about variants of usage.  A good example is "modeling" and "modelling," which should be synonyms.  But how does one go about making fixes?  By posting questions in meta (like this one)?

Comment: @whuber I am not sure about the process. Perhaps, one of the mods have an insight?